# How to install pLaTeX in OpenIndiana/Solaris?

Tags: installing, japanese, platex

I'm using OpenIndiana (151a/x86) for my work, and want to use pLaTeX in Japanese.

However, there are no pLaTeX packages prepared for OpenIndiana (so far), so I probably need to compile it by myself.

I need the following commands to be installed in my computer.

- platex
- dvipdfm(x)
- xdvi

I want to know the following facts, as possible.

1. Where can I get the latest source code (for Solaris)?
2. What libraries/packages do I need for compiling?
3. Are there any known problems?

Note : I know that pLaTeX works on Solaris, because I used to write my reports using pLaTeX with Solaris 9 when I was an University student. I just don't know HOW it can be installed in my OpenIndiana machine...

Comment: Not that I can read Japanese at all, but had you already seen any of the following: [optix.org](http://www.optix.org/~dxy/solaris/ptex/), [kyoto-u.ac.jp](http://www-an.acs.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~fujiwara/tex/tetex.html), or [takuma-ct.ac.jp](http://www.dt.takuma-ct.ac.jp/~kmanabe/memo/platex.html)? Each appears to be someone's notes on Solaris builds of pTeX and its dependencies.